# Copy some values from one ArrayList to another kotlin

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin

I have list:

```
var skillsList: MutableList<ComplexModel> = mutableListOf()
```

ComplexModel contains (Name,Title,StartDate,Summarry)

I want to find better way to create new MutableList from **skillsList** but the new list have to get only Name and Title from the first.For the moment i`m with this solution but i wonder if there are better way to achieve this.

```
   val newArray: MutableList<SkillModel> = mutableListOf()

    for (skill in skillsList) {
        newArray.add(SkillModel(name = skill.name, title = skill.title))
    }
```

Comment: You can use the `map` function of collections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var skills: List<SkillModel> = skillsList.map { SkillModel(it.name,it.title) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get you correctly, how about using `map {}` for achieving the same without for loop.

Example:

```
data class X(val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int)
data class Y(val a: Int, val b: Int)

val lista = listOf( X(1,2,3), X(2,3,1) )
val listb = lista.map { Y(it.a, it.b) }

println(listb) // -> gives [Y(a=1, b=2), Y(a=2, b=3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my list whose elements i want to copy:

```
    private var responseList = ArrayList<QuizQuestion>()
```

This is the method for it:

```
    private var ans = createAnswerList(responseList)

 private fun createAnswerList(ques: List<QuizQuestion>): List<AnswerList> {
    var answerList = ArrayList<AnswerList>()
    for (i in ques.indices) {
        answerList.add(AnswerList(ques[i].answer, ques[i].id))
    }
    return answerList
}
```